# Rest api for my orders

Tags: magento2, product, orders, api, rest-api

Where can i find the rest api for my orders and my downloadable products  in magento2. I can't find the list in the swagger file.

eg: 
GET `/orders/me`
GET `/downloadableproducts/me`

Or how can i filter it based on existing api

Comment: its there with the name salesOrderRepositoryV1

Comment: also you can apply filters as seen here to filter the downloadable products https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804095/magento-2-rest-api-product-filters

Comment: salesOrderRepositoryV1 is not available to customers. All API routes in the sales module are specified with an ACL of `Magento_Sales::sales`.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.5/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/webapi.xml#L10-L15

Answer (score 0):

By default magento doesn't have API that allows to customer get his own orders.
You can find all available order's API requests in
`vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/webapi.xml`.

But you can use endpoint GET `/V1/orders` for that - just pass customer_id with searchCriteria and it will return all needed orders.